# Should I sync redux between tabs?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building an ERP web application in which the redux state contains many table data and logged in user data.

I was wondering whether should I sync my redux state across multiple tabs since:

- The tables are empty and are fetched from the API on each tab separately.
- The user is required to login in each tab.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The tables are empty and are fetched from the API on each tab
> separately.

If the data comes from the api server should be used across the app components, not in one component or in one-level deep child component (to prevent Prop drilling), you should update redux store with api data. In other case, you can simply store them in component-level state solution like *useState API* and render your *functional* component when needed (*state* object and *setState* method for class-based components).

> The user is required to login in each tab.

You can implement and control this logic in component, where you organize and handle your app routes. Your app routes can be handled by e.g. *react-router*  library and your app components can be rendered by some condition: *isLoggedIn* or *not*.